# Express Microservices on NGINX reverse proxy in docker environment; a random microservice always times out

Tags: docker, express, nginx, docker-compose, nginx-reverse-proxy

A few peers and I are working on a project where we have 3 microservices, all express APIs, and use a docker-compose to bring them, a React front-end, and an nginx reverse proxy into a singular environment. The weird thing is that when all three of the microservices are running, one of them hangs / times out while the other two are fine, and whenever I only include any combination of two microservices in the proxy they both work. Another weird thing is that it is only happening on one of my peer's computers, while the rest of us don't have this issue.

Each server is running fine on its own, no errors. Perhaps this is a load balancer issue, or there aren't enough processes to run the microservices? Thank you so much in advance for your help!

**nginx.config file (which includes a commented out microservice as an example of how i tested this theory):**

```
# upstream api1 {
#     server api1:5001;
# }

upstream api2 {
    server api2:5002;
}

upstream api3 {
    server api3:5003;
}


server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    listen [::]:80 default_server;
    server_name _;
    add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' 'http://localhost:3000' always;
    add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials' 'true' always;
    add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Headers' 'Authorization,Accept,Origin,DNT,X-CustomHeader,Keep-Alive,User-Agent,X-Requested-With,If-Modified-Since,Cache-Control,Content-Type,Content-Range,Range' always;
    add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Methods' 'GET,POST,OPTIONS,PUT,DELETE,PATCH' always;

    # location /api1 {
    #     rewrite ^/api1/(.*) /$1 break;
    #     proxy_pass http://api1/;
    #     proxy_http_version 1.1;
    #     proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
    #     proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
    #     proxy_set_header Host $host;
    #     proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    #     proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    # }
    location /api2 {
        rewrite ^/api2/(.*) /$1 break;
        proxy_pass http://api2/;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    }
    location /api3 {
        rewrite ^/api3/(.*) /$1 break;
        proxy_pass http://api3/;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    }
}
```

**docker-compose.yml file:**

```
version: '3.8'

services:
    web-app:
        container_name: web-app-dev
        build:
            context: ./web-app
            target: development
        volumes:
            - /app/node_modules
            - ./web-app:/app
        ports:
            - 3000:3000
        depends_on: [api1, api2, api3]
    api1:
        container_name: api1-dev
        build:
            context: ./api1
            target: development
        volumes:
            - /app/node_modules
            - ./api1:/app
        ports:
            - 5001:5000
        depends_on:
            - nginx
    api2:
        container_name: api2-dev
        build:
            context: ./api2
            target: development
        volumes:
            - /app/node_modules
            - ./api2:/app
        ports:
            - 5002:5000
        depends_on:
            - nginx
    api3:
        container_name: api3-dev
        build:
            context: ./api3
            target: development
        volumes:
            - /app/node_modules
            - ./api3:/app
        ports:
            - 5003:5000
        depends_on:
            - nginx

    nginx:
        restart: always
        image: nginx:latest
        container_name: nginx
        volumes:
            - ./api-gateway/default.conf:/etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
        ports:
            - 8080:80
            - 80:80
```

**current folder structure:**

```
- docker-compose.yml
- api-gateway folder
- api1 folder
- api2 folder
- api3 folder
- web-app folder
```

**example of a Dockerfile in one of the microservices:**

```
FROM node:16-alpine AS development
ENV NODE_ENV development
# Add a work directory
WORKDIR /app
# Cache and Install dependencies
COPY package.json .
COPY yarn.lock .
RUN yarn install
# Copy app files
COPY . .
# Expose port
EXPOSE 5002:5000
# Start the app
CMD [ "yarn", "dev" ]
```

- Have tried fetching all servers outside of the proxy to make sure they are up when one is timing out, and can confirm that they are all working.
- Have tried removing each of the microservices and leaving the other two in the nginx.config file, and the two included in the proxy work.
- Have changed the ports from also being on 8080 to being on 5000, issue persisted.